# Voice chat software for communicating through LAN (does not require an Internet connection)

Tags: windows, chat, lan, voip

I'm looking for software that can be used for voice chatting through LAN. The software will be mainly for home use and while playing LAN games. Due to our spotty Internet connection, and to avoid quickly reaching the bandwidth cap imposed by our ISP, we'd rather play through and talk through LAN.

Requirements:

- Does not require an Internet connection to use, only a LAN connection
- Works on Windows 7

Preferably:

- Can detect when a computer in the LAN has the software running and can be called
- Easy to setup and use
- Can call a computer by its IP address
- Has good audio quality
- Freeware

We've already tried the [SSuite Voip PC Phone Extreme](http://www.ssuitesoft.com/voippcphonelanchat.htm) software, and it does fit my requirements and most of my preferences, but its audio quality is unacceptably low as per our tests.

Comment: Does it need to be serverless, or are you ok with running your own server in the lan?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek It doesn't need to be serverless. Though, I'd prefer software that has no need to login to or setup a server, and is more of a P2P software. Most of the time, only two people will be using the software, anyway.

Answer (score 9):

I would recommend [Mumble](http://mumble.sourceforge.net/)

> Mumble is an open source, low-latency, high quality voice chat software primarily intended for use while gaming.

Some notable features include

- Low latency, high quality, encrypted communication
- Channel interface
- [Manageable group and user based permissions](http://mumble.sourceforge.net/ACL_and_Groups)
- Optional In-Game Overlay
- [Positional audio](http://mumble.sourceforge.net/Positional-Audio)

[image: Mumble]

Mumble is free, open source, and available on Windows, Linux, and OS X.

The only possible caveat is that Mumble does require a server to connect to. This server, [Murmur](https://wiki.mumble.info/wiki/Running_Murmur) is available on Windows and Linux. It might also be good to note that [Murmur does not take much to run](https://serverfault.com/questions/11635/how-many-resources-does-a-mumble-server-need).

Answer (score 1):

You can use any software, that allows you to setup a server. It's entierly up to you what you will chose.

It can be be Mumble (as stated above), Ventrillo, TeamSpeak or any other software that allows to setup a server.

Then you can connect through local IP to it.

Comment: Upvoted for Teamspeak.

Answer (score 0):

## [PicoPhone](http://www.vitez.it/picophone/index.html)

PicoPhone is a very simple and portable IP phone program for one-to-one calls or conference calls. I've heard of it, but I don't use it because it's not as ubiquitous as Skype (I prefer Jabber/XMPP, but again, none of my friends use Jabber). The program  "phones home" only once to grab your public IP and retrieve available Picoservers, but it still works if no connection is available.

[image]